# Import on Client Side Only on Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, vite, nuxt3

I am trying to use a library that seems to work on client side only. Below is the page source code

**pages/test.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>Pig</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import '@/assets/js/RongIMLib-2.5.4.min.js'

onMounted(() => {
  const RongIMClient = RongIMLib.RongIMClient
  RongIMClient.init('xxxxx', null)
})
</script>
```

It works when it is visited by router link on the browser but if you hist refresh, it will then return an error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```